# Не работает удаленная отладка IDE Gogland (1.0 EAP) через delve

Tags: golang, отладка, ide, jetbrains

Здравствуйте! Кто работает с GO и IDE Gogland нужна ваша помощь.

Пытаюсь организовать удаленную отладку утилиты с помощью пакета Delve 
https://github.com/derekparker/delve/

Установил по инструкции, запускаю на простом примере:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
    for i:=uint(0); i< 10; i++{
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

ВЫВОД:

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2
API server listening at: [::]:2345
```

Запускаю удаленную отладку в IDE:

```
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:493: halting
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x47bb52, File:"/....../hello/hello.go", Line:6, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:23:24 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:23:28 debugger.go:516: nexting
hello world
2017/07/20 17:23:28 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
0
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
02017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
1
2017/07/20 17:23:29 debugger.go:516: nexting
12017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
42017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
3
2017/07/20 17:23:30 debugger.go:516: nexting
92017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
4
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
162017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:31 debugger.go:516: nexting
5
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
252017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
6
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
362017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:32 debugger.go:516: nexting
7
2017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
492017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:33 debugger.go:516: nexting
8
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
642017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
9
2017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
812017/07/20 17:23:34 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:35 debugger.go:516: nexting
2017/07/20 17:23:35 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

Все работает.

Но как только запускаю на своем рабочем проекте, то после запуска сразу пишет вот это и все висит.

```
dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2 -- --v --console
2017/07/20 17:26:51 debugger.go:97: launching process with args: [/home/...../debug --v --console]
API server listening at: [::]:2345
```

Запускаю удаленную отладку в IDE:

```
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:493: halting
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x687a73, File:"/home/..........go", Line:136, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:2, Name:"", Addr:0x6869b2, File:"/home/..........go", Line:66, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:3, Name:"", Addr:0x687d33, File:"/home/........go", Line:143, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:26:55 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:26:57 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

Мне кажется причина этого - вот это сообщение:

**2017/07/20 17:26:45 debugger.go:493: halting**

Почему оно возникает?? Может быть у меня структура утилиты сложная (main пакет разбит на несколько файлов, естественно есть внешние подключаемые пакеты и т.д.) или еще что то?

НО(!!!) самое интересное, что если присоединяться к удаленному серверу не через IDE, а через консоль, то отладка работает и на простом примере и в случае моей утилиты:

```
dlv connect HOSTNAME:2345
Type 'help' for list of commands.
(dlv) b ********.go:137
Breakpoint 1 set at 0x687a86 for main.main() /home/*************.go:137
(dlv) c
> main.main() /home/***************************.go:137 (hits goroutine(1):1 total:1) (PC: 0x687a86)
(dlv) n
```

Вывод отладчика:

```
$ dlv debug --headless --listen=:2345 --log --api-version=2 -- --v --console
2017/07/20 17:37:37 debugger.go:97: launching process with args: [/home/*****************/debug --v --console]
API server listening at: [::]:2345
2017/07/20 17:38:27 debugger.go:347: created breakpoint: &api.Breakpoint{ID:1, Name:"", Addr:0x687a86, File:"/home/*******************.go", Line:137, FunctionName:"main.main", Cond:"", Tracepoint:false, Goroutine:false, Stacktrace:0, Variables:[]string(nil), LoadArgs:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), LoadLocals:(*api.LoadConfig)(nil), HitCount:map[string]uint64{}, TotalHitCount:0x0}
2017/07/20 17:38:35 debugger.go:504: continuing
2017/07/20 17:38:39 debugger.go:516: nexting
```

Т.е. напрашивается подозрение на ошибку в IDE, либо я что то делаю не так :).

Спасибо за время уделенное на вопрос, очень надеюсь на помощь.

P.S. Буду также рад узнать что еще можно использовать для удаленной отладки.

P.P.S. Попробовал сделать удаленную отладку в Atom.io и в VS code

В Атоме работает локальный дебагер через dlv. 
В VS code работает локальный дебагер через dlv + работает удаленный дебагер, НО не работают брейкпойнты!!! Т.е. VS Code тоже не выход.
Настройка VS Code (launch.json)

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "REMOTE",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "remote",
            "remotePath": "{workspaceRoot}",
            "port": 2345,
            "host": "REMOTE_HOST_NAME",
            "program":  "${workspaceRoot}", //"${fileDirname}",
            "env": {},
            "args": ["--v", "--console"],
            "showLog": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в IDE. Была исправлена начиная с версии 
Build: EAP 12, 172.3757.46
Released: Aug 11, 2017